# Custom payment via voice assistant apps

Tags: amazon-web-services, payment, alexa-skills-kit, assistant

We have a website with payment possibilities. We're also developing skills for Amazon Alexa and Google Assistant, and users can link account with our system. Are we allowed to let users make payments/transactions through our system through these voice apps?

Comment: I think all Alexa-related payment are provided via AmazonPay - https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/amazon-pay-alexa/integrate-skill-with-amazon-pay.html Does it answer your question?

Comment: I am aware of its existence. My question is, is it mandatory to use Amazon Pay or are we allowed to use our custom payment gateway?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Amazon Pay](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/amazon-pay-alexa/amazon-pay-overview.html) or [account linking](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/link-an-alexa-user-with-a-user-in-your-system.html). If you use account linking you need to provide order details, PIN validation, etc. Have a look at [this document](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/requirements-for-skills-that-allow-purchases.html) for more details.